# when to use bash with option -c?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand `-c` option for bash better. The man page says:

> `-c`: If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string. If there are arguments after the command_string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

I'm having trouble understanding what this means.

If I do the following command with and without bash -c, I get the same result (example from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html):

```
$ set w x y z; IFS=":-;"; echo "$*"
w:x:y:z
$ bash -c 'set w x y z; IFS=":-;"; echo "$*"'
w:x:y:z
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: BTW, the ABS is not a good choice of references -- it has a reputation for showcasing bad practices (in the words of [the irc.freenode.org #bash IRC bot](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs), it'll "teach you to write bugs, not scripts"). Consider either [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) or [the Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash -c` isn't as interesting when *you're already running bash*. Consider, on the other hand, the case when you want to run bash code from a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
fileOne='hello'
fileTwo='world'

p = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'diff <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2")',
                      '_',     # this is $0 inside the bash script above
                      fileOne, # this is $1
                      fileTwo, # and this is $2
                     ])
print p.communicate() # run that bash interpreter, and print its stdout and stderr
```

Here, because we're using bash-only syntax (`<(...)`), you couldn't run this with anything that used POSIX sh by default, which is the case for `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)`; using `bash -c` thus provides access to capabilities that wouldn't otherwise be available without playing with FIFOs yourself.

---

Incidentally, this isn't the only way to do that: One could also use `bash -s`, and pass code in on stdin. Below, that's being done not from Python but POSIX sh (`/bin/sh`, which likewise is not guaranteed to have `<(...)` available):

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...this is POSIX sh code, not bash code; you can't use <() here
# ...so, if we want to do that, one way is as follows:

fileOne=hello
fileTwo=world

bash -s "$fileOne" "$fileTwo" <<'EOF'
# the inside of this heredoc is bash code, not POSIX sh code
diff <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2")
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` option finds its most important uses when `bash` is launched by another program, and especially when the code to be executed may or does include redirections, pipelines, shell built-ins, shell variable assignments, and / or non-trivial lists.  On POSIX systems that have `/bin/sh` being an alias for `bash`, it specifically supports the C library's `system()` function.

Equivalent behavior is much trickier to implement on top of fork / exec without using `-c`, though not altogether impossible.

Answer (score 1):

How to execute BASH code from *outside the BASH shell*?

The answer is, using the `-c` option, which makes BASH execute whatever that has been passed as an argument to `-c`.

So, yeah, this is the purpose of this option, to execute BASH code arbitrarily, but just in another way.